# Getting UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY error while we use react-native-navigation V2 along with react-native-youtube

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I have used react-native-navigation V2 along with react-native-youtube.
when I play the video then it will pause automatically with error

10-30 10:59:35.613 18102-18102/com.xyz W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: **YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player**. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.widget.FrameLayout{91b1c4c V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1857}. **YouTubePlayerView is completely covered**, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 54, top: 734, right: 53, bottom: 514..

This error is happening bcoz in V2 there is something new support adding for overlay manager before root is setting, while in v1 everything works perfectly.

Comment: Same here
any solution?